# VSCode API - intercept and change search value before executing search

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to write a VSCode extension that will apply a regex pattern to every search. Can this be done? I want this for folder search and inline search.

Comment: how often are you going to ask this, this is already the third time in 2 days

Comment: @rioV8 this is the last time, I already deleted the previous ones.

Comment: You need to explain in more detail what you are trying to do.  You can already make a keybinding that will do a search with any regex.  And what is "inline search"?